# Raspbery Pi can only open "hid.pyx" running as root

Tags: python, usb, raspberry-pi4, udev

`import hid` cannot access USB relay as pi user, only as root:

System Info:
raspberry pi 4
python 3.9

Test pi user:

```
pi@raspi:~ $ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hid
>>> dev = hid.device()
>>> dev.open(5824,1503)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "hid.pyx", line 127, in hid.device.open
OSError: open failed
>>>
```

Test root user:
When I run the code with root privileges it works

```
root@raspi:/home/pi# python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hid
>>> dev = hid.device()
>>> dev.open(5824,1503)
>>>
```

I created the following role with root (there is no other way) 99-personal.rules Folder: /etc/udev/rules.d

> KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="5824", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1503",> MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"

updated with:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
```

I've also tried restarting the Pi and unplugging the USB relay cable and plugging it back in
What do I have to do so that the pi user also has the right to execute?

Comment: This seems more like a Linux/Sysadmin question than a Python question so maybe [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) is a better place?

Comment: you could also ask on similar portal for [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or on official [forum Raspberry Pi](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/)

Comment: I always had before with an existing group (plugdev) My last attempt was to create a new group "usbrelay" and assign the pi user

If someone has the same problem, it would be worth a try ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  What I did was add a single like to /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="0660"
```

My limited understanding is that this makes the `usb` subsystem accessible to anyone in the `plugdev` group (i.e. the default user group).  After rebooting, I was able to access the hid device without running as root.